# What does Computer-in-the-loop or CIL mean related to embedded systems

Tags: embedded

Im trying to learn more about embedded systems. During some of my research I have come across references to CIL or HWIL (apparently Computer-In-Loop or Hardware-In-Loop). I have not found much of an explanation in terms of CIL. Could someone elaborate a bit more on what this typically references? Is it possibly related to testing scenarios in a simulation environment?

Answer (score 1):

These are terms I have never used before because I was never in the 'merican military which use 3 and 4 letter abbreviations like crazy.  But basically you start with precise parameters and values for every source of error on every interface and then validate the design on those parameters.

e.g.

> Monte Carlo runsets using known CIL/HWIL interface errors, such as scale factor, bias and noise, are used to create minimum-maximum boundary value plots.

Although I have worked for and with many American Corporations, the common terms we used are: Design Specs; DVT plan, PVT plan, HALT, HASS and Tolerance Stackup.

- DVT = Design Verification ( or Validation) Test plan (& results) that verfies EVERY spec and in my case, test to failure or margin to failure. Uses every Design Spec.
- PVT= Production or Process Verification Test  Uses DVT results to fine tune for production tolerance verification and ALL design Specs.
- HALT= Highly Accelerated Life Testing ( like shock and vibe with Temp stress while running voltage margins on supply with crystal tolerance errors , then increase until failure occurs)
- HASS = Highly Accelerated Stress Screening ( like above but not to stressed to failure mode) and used for quality screening and burnin.
- For complex process with many e.g. 10 variables such as pre-flux and wave-soldering, Taguchi Method is used.
- For embedded code work, this means doing worst case input and output test vectors to ensure all faults are detected, reported or corrected. and every Function is validated.  Design Specs are a MUST for HIPO design specs. Heirarchical Input Process Output. ( an IBM acronym)  For complex IO processes, TAguchi Method can be used to reduce number of experiments to determine process sensitivity of each variable.

Answer (score 1):

When I have hear of CIL used in the context of embedded programming, it usually means automated testing done on a mock system, rather than simulation.

One way to test an embedded microcontroller would be run in a simulator, wither by mocking the IO routines or using logs generated by the simulator.  So your test is "under stimulus X, data Y needs to be sent to peripheral Z within t clock cycles."  This is nice if you can do it because it can be run completely in software.  This makes it easy to automate with a build system and do lots and lots of runs.  It also may be easier to inject faults or do internal inspection like monitor state machine transitions.

This approach has some limitations as well.  First, it is simply difficult to do.  Embedded systems are designed to "talk to the world" constantly, and generating a simulation environment that captures that sufficiently well can be difficult.  Second, the tests don't necessarily reflect the true constraints -- lets say that peripheral Z above is some SPI or CAN bus chip.  What you actually care about is that the peripheral does what it is supposed to.  If your test doesn't capture the timing requirements of that peripheral, then your test won't detect that type of error.

So a HWIL test would mean that when you build the program, you flash it to a "test" platform, then perform the tests on real hardware, and e.g., log the results with a logic analyzer or oscilloscope.  If your test is that "if the accelerometer goes above some value, fire the airbag", then you are actually testing the pulse that would go to the airbag inflater, rather than simply that the correct IO routine gets called on the microprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

While there are probably official definitions for the terms, the line between CIL and HWIL often vary from group to group.  Ask your customer for clarification as to what they generally mean.

As I am lead to understand it, CIL means you have the actual computer in the loop, meaning the actual CPU and other data processing chips.  You then exercise the software using simulated inputs and outputs.

As I am lead to understand it, HWIL means you have not only the actual computer, but you also have other hardware devices such as sensors or actuators involved.  HWIL testing lets you shake down errors which may arise from the sensors and actuators not behaving *exactly* as they did in simulation. (because we all know that every hardware product behaves exactly as simulated)

As an example, if you had an embedded solution which was a motion detector using an IR camera, a CIL setup might generate simulated imagery and pipe it into the CPU as a stream of data. A HWIL setup testing the same product might generate simulated imagery, project it onto a screen in front of a real IR camera, and attach the IR camera to the CPU.